# Does damping cause a gradual change in frequency?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, frequency, oscillators, vibrations, dissipation

Consider a vibrating cantilever in a system where air resistance is taken into account. The air causes the damping of the cantilever's oscillation. As a result, does the frequency of the vibration change *during* the vibrating?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is angular frequency dependent on time in damped harmonic motion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136535/)

Comment: Damping causes an immediate change in frequency, but it takes time for you to measure the frequency.

Answer (score 0):

For objects vibrating in air and transferring kinetic energy into the air (i.e., being *damped* by friction with the air), the resonant frequency is decreased in proportion to the amount of damping. For large amplitudes you get large amounts of damping and the vibrating object plays "flat". The smaller the amplitude of vibration, the slower the object is moving and the less frictional losses there are, and the frequency of vibration rises back "to pitch" by a small amount.

So yes, the frequency of vibration changes while the vibrations are occurring, if you start the system vibrating with a large enough initial impulse.

Comment: Could you elaporate? as the solution to a damped harmonic oscillator has a fixed frequency.

Comment: There is a standard formula which furnishes the resonant frequency as a function of the amount of damping for any RLC system; it illustrates how the *damped* natural frequency is lower that the *undamped* case.